# Is the following function tail call optmized?

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion

I am new to haskell (first time trying fn programming) and just trying out various exercises from "real world haskell" book. Can someone please correct me and tell if the below function is tail call optimized or not? If yes, then could you correct me how is it done? I am adding 1 to the recursive function so i believe this should throw a stackoverflow exception?

I tried calling myLength [1..2000000] but it didn't throw any stackoverflow exception

```
myLength (x:xs) = 1 + myLength(xs) 
myLength [] = 0
```

Comment: The default stack size with GHC is 8MB. You may have simply not exceeded it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GHC can likely optimize this to be tail-call recursive, but the way you've written it is not.  In order to be tail-call recursive, the "top" function in the tree has to be the recursive call.  When I run your code in GHCi with `[1..20000000000000]`, it runs out of memory with a segmentation fault, so it will not work for very large inputs.

If we re-arrange your definition a bit, I think it'll make it a bit more clear as to why it isn't TCR:

```
myLength (x:xs) =
    (+)
        1
        (myLength xs)
myLength [] = 0
```

Here I've broken it down into what is essentially a tree, and could be represented like

```
        (+)
       /   \
      /     \
     1     myLength
              \
               xs
```

So as you can see, the last function to be called in this tree is `(+)`, not `myLength`.  To fix this, you can use the fold pattern:

```
myLength = go 0
    where
        go acc (x:xs) = go (1 + acc) xs
        go acc []     = acc
```

And now the tree looks like

```
             go
           /    \
         (+)     xs
        /   \
       1    acc
```

So the top function in the tree is `go`, which is the recursive call.  Alternatively, you can use a built-in fold to implement this.  To keep from building up a lot of thunks, my recommendation would be to use `foldl'` from `Data.List`:

```
myLength = foldl' (\acc x -> acc + 1) 0
```

And while this may take a very long time to execute, it will not blow up the stack nor will it build up thunks that eat up RAM.

---

But as @DonStewart says, the compiler has a fair amount of freedom in re-arranging your code during optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

Naively, this uses the stack. But the language doesn't specific the operational semantics, so a compiler is free to reorder things as long as it doesn't change the observed strictness.

Answer (score 1):

no, this is not a tail-calling function (the last call in the non-empty list case will be `+` but this is not a big deal in Haskell (see [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion) for some details).

So you don't need to restructure it but if you want you can do it with an accumulator:

```
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength = myLength' 0
  where myLength' acc [] = acc
        myLength' acc (_:xs) = myLength' (acc+1) xs
```

if we want to make Carl (a bit more) happy we can get rid of some thunks (without overcomplicating it to much - or so I think , I'm not that good when it comes to lazyness in Haskell, sorry):

```
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength = myLength' 0
  where myLength' acc []     = acc
        myLength' acc xs     = let acc' = acc+1
                               in seq acc' $ myLength' acc' (tail xs)
```

Comment: Huh. Any reason you suggested the only variant guaranteed to be worse than the original code? While this is tail recursive, it's tail recursive in the way that guarantees wasting a ton of memory.

Comment: nope - no particular reason besides from this beeing the easiest way you usually do it. There are lots of answers now and just go on and add a better way to your answer - I'm sure we all can be reasonable enlightened by it

Answer (score 0):

Tail call elimination is automatic in GHC (you don't mention what compiler you're using, so I'll assume the most common) because of the calling convention GHC uses. But you have to be very wary of what the tail call actually *is*.  In your definition, the tail call is `(+)`.

As far as I know, GHC doesn't have any optimizations that will change that to a more memory-efficient form, and I suspect @Ferruccio 's comment is on to something.